# Where can I find an extension or website with PHP user snippets to be used in an HTML file? (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I recently installed the extension PHP Awesome Snippets of Visual Studio Code, which includes lots of useful snippets for PHP programming. However, the snippets of this extension can only be used within php tags.

For example, if you want to get the following structure in HTML:

```
<?php if(): ?>
        
<?php endif; ?>
```

You won't be able to get it by typing the 'ifen' snippet of this extension in HTML.

Now the question is: do you know any extension for Visual Code Studio that provides a list of snippets similar to PHP Awesome Snippets but that are also available to use in an HTML file? In case there isn't such extension, do you know of any website where someone has shared a list of them (with the code to incorporate in the HTML.json file)?

I can't imagine everyone is hardcoding User Snippets for this, when it seems to me something that is very often repeated by many people, but so far I haven't found any extension nor website for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Relevant extension is this [PHP Snippets VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=heberalmeida.php-snippets) on the marketplace which works even inside html files without the `<?php` tag declaration.

[image]

Since that extension doesn't have any settings for itself. The easy way of doing this is to create a workspace setting file, `settings.json` in you `project/.vscode/` folder.

And add this to the settings

**settings.json**

```js
{
  // all other settings

  "files.associations": {
   "*.html": "php",    
  }
}
```

**.code-workspace** file

```js
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "files.associations": {
            "*.html": "php",    
         }
    }
}
```

What this does is tell VScode to treat all HTML files as PHP. It shouldn't be much of an issue because, Emmet snippets will work along with the snippets from this extension.

This is better to be added as workspace/project setting because, it won't affect other projects where you might be working on another language.

One more way is to doing manually file by file, if you want to. You can click on the language identifier in the status bar and change it to PHP and you will enable snippets in the file.

[image: language identifier]

Comment: Hello tHeSiD, thank you for the answer but none of the solutions work for me. In the first case, I paste your code in my .code-workspace file for the workspace and it is even grayed out as if something wrong happened with the code. Trying the single-file approach didn't change anything either. As I wrote ifel no PHP Awesome Snippet appeared (I tried with several snippet prefixes).

Comment: Oh, even in html the you need the <?php tag because thats how the extension is designed. I don't think you are gonna use those snippets outside the php tag anyway. 

I also updated the ans on how a workspace file should look. try that.

Comment: Another thing, if you have a `.code-workspace` file, everything in the `./.vscode/` folder will be ignored thats why it looks greyed out

Comment: Hello again tHeSid, of course it does work once you create the php tags and place the cursor inside. I appreciate your effort, this can be a useful workaround for some cases but it is far from being the accepted answer. As you can imagine, what I'm looking for are snippets that help you tab both inside php tags and outside, for cases as the one I provided in the info of this question.

Comment: I added an extension link to the answer, it has the basic snippets but it works without using any `<?php` tag declaration. Just out of curiosity, why  would you want to write php code outside of the php tags?

Comment: Look, I created a short clip with one user snippet that I had to manually create for this purpose. As you can see, it gives me the freedom, using tabstops, to edit both inside php and outside php tags (with Emmet). This is an easy example with an if conditional, imagine the power with an if else conditional or a foreach where you code both inside php tags and outside. This is way harder to achieve with your workaround proposal. Clip: https://imgur.com/gallery/Zs2gVrS?s=wa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216507/discussion-between-thesid-and-assensi).